# Is it always necessary to use components in vuejs even though they might not get reused

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vue.js

I have a question that has been going through my mind for a while now. Should every component created be reusable??
Let's suppose that we have some html,css and javascript that can't get reused. For example a CRUD table for a specific product ( for example CRUD of users )  that gets updated through methods and watchers and other stuff. It could be created as a component called UsersTable but then that component can't get reused since it has the methods relative to users management through DB.
So for example, should that component be declared as plain html/css and js inside the parent  or should it be declared as a component and emit events in order to communicate with its parent?

Comment: Hey there! This question is a little broad for StackOverflow, which is more oriented around non-opinion based questions - perhaps ask at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: The answer is, this always depends. Components is a way to structure the code, not just reuse it.

Comment: If reusability was the only valid reason for defining components you'd get the contents of `App.vue` inside `main.(js|ts)` in a fresh new Vue application. `HellowWorld.vue`, too. It's not reused, right?

Comment: You got a point @tao

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a datatable component that doesn't care from what domain the information comes that it displays?

Comment: I would agree but i'm still a beginner, I literally found out today that Bootstrap Vue for example has a datatable feature that does that automatically. I didn't have an idea about it at that time so I coded everything by myself ( API Fetching , CRUD operations...). Moreover, I recently found out that every package you install has its dependencies added to the package.json so having it in there would make the project work on other devices in a proper way since everything is going to get installed automatically

Answer (score 0):

For the point of reusing a component, it would be better if we could define a `BaseTable` component with some options:

1. It will be a [Dynamic Component](https://blog.logrocket.com/making-components-dynamic-vue-3/) which allows us to specify or definite a component to be rendered. So if we have two different table templates called `UserTable.vue` and `ProducTable.vue`, we can decide which template will be rendered by passing the name in the `is` directive:

```
    <component :is=”UserTable”></component>
```

2. It will be defined with some [Named Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots) and then we can determine the different slot contents in `UserTable` and `ProductTable`:

```
    <thead><slot name="thead"></slot></thead>
```

3. If the table template is fixed, then it will be the most simple case, as we can define an object that contains the config of the table (header, column), and then pass this object as a props to `BaseTable`: